# When to use servlet and when to use service in aem to implement any particular logic

Tags: servlets, service, aem, aem-6

I'm want to know the use cases of the servlet and service. Although we can perform the same logic using any of the two but I'm not sure about the specific use cases of servlet and service.

Comment: My advice would be to attend both a Java and an AEM training.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of AEM:
 - Servlets are used to expose a URL to the outside world
 - Services are used to expose a class on the OSGI stack

You create a servlet with annotations like:

```
@Component(property = { 
    "sling.servlet.paths = /path/that/you/like",
    "sling.servlet.methods = GET" 
})
```

Making http://yoursite.com/path/that/you/like work, assuming your dispatchers let that path through. You call the URL, things happen.

Services are INTERNAL classes that can be used in servlets, components, other services, other modules on the OSGI stack, etc...

You create a service annotations like:

```
@Component(service = MyService.class, immediate = true)
```

Which can them be used by other classes with injection

```
@Reference
private MyService service;
```

That service could be used by your bundle internally, or by other bundles if you expose it in your build.